# Visualise high dimensional data - returns of n-asset portfolio as 2D plot, like heatmap?

Tags: data-visualization, dimensionality-reduction, high-dimensional

It's possible to visualise both **asset allocations and returns** of 2-assets portfolio as 2D heatmap.

Like in image below, the visualisation of $[Gold, Silver]$ portfolio with restriction $Gold + Silver = 1$. Color and size of circle represent the returns for given asset allocation.

[image]

What are the ways to somehow represent 5-asset (and in general N-assets) portfolio as 2D plot? Some dimensionality reduction technics, clustering similar portfolios or other tricks?

It should somehow show or hint both - **asset allocation and returns**.

Why - to better understand what's going on. Visually access the performance how it changes with asset allocation changes, how smooth the surface is, if there's no jumps, get some insights from it, if it looks reasonable or not, etc. Maybe make it interactive or as animation.